# Hide datatable when no records found

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want hide my datatable when user applies filter and no records found, we can set custom msg, but my requirement is hide this table. below is my sample code.I am unable to figure which listener will help when no records found will hide table.

```
reportCardTbl = $('.standardDataTable').DataTable( {
    "paging": false,
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "paging": false,
    "oLanguage": {
        "sZeroRecords":function(){
            //$(this) gives me TD, i tried to search $(this).parents("table").hide(); not working as TD is not in table
            //here i want to hide table 
        }
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use fnDrawCallback:

```
reportCardTbl = $(".standardDataTable").dataTable({
    "paging": false,
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    fnDrawCallback: function (settings) {
        $(".standardDataTable").parent().toggle(settings.fnRecordsDisplay() > 0);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. I have changed fnDrawCallback as $(".standardDataTable") may have multiple tables.                    fnDrawCallback: function (settings) {
            $("#"+settings.sTableId).toggle(settings.fnRecordsDisplay() > 0);
        }

Comment: @Akash, thanks a lot for this. It helped me to solve one of my problems.